# Question regarding PermissionEx (WIX)

Tags: permissions, wix, wix3

I am new to WIX. I am using util:PermissionEx for creating ACLs. I can successfully set rights like read, write, read & execute but I am unable to find any information about setting Modify Permission.

I have tried using "Append" attribute to achieve this functionality (this seems to be the only attribute that may do the desired)

But using this, the following compilation error appears:
"error CNDL0004: The util:PermissionEx element contains an unexpected attribute 'Append'."

Could you please help me out in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My question, and answer-to-self at [WiX Permissions, how do I express 'Modify' in terms of DACL flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301503/wix-permissions-how-do-i-express-modify-in-terms-of-dacl-flags) may assist in some way in terms of mapping the simple right Modify to specific rights.

Looking at the doc, the Append attribute definitely seems to be permitted - what build of Wix [3] are you using? With the latest version, you should be able to remove util: and Ex from your tag as it all seems to be natiuvely supported now. Other examples also show an `Extended` attribute, which is not accepted by newer versions.